# Adding padding to Y-axis of d3 Scatter Plot

Tags: javascript, php, css, d3.js, visualization

I am creating a Scatter plot to show the different categories of websites a user has visited over time.

The plot can be see in an image below, as you can see the category 'computer' is inline with the X-axis, is there anyway to add padding to the bottom of the Y-axis so that it is above and not inline with the X-axis?

Thanks

```
<script>
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 80},
    width = 1440 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 750 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scalePoint().range([height, 0]);

// Get the data
var data = <?php echo $URLJsonData; ?>;
var data1 = <?php echo $DownloadsJsonData; ?>;


// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
});

data1.forEach(function (d) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date); 
});

data.push(data1);
data = [].concat.apply([], data);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.type); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.type; }));


  // Add the scatterplot
    svg.selectAll("dot")    
        .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")                               
        .attr("r", 3.5)     
        .attr('fill-opacity', 0.48672)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.RiskScore > 0) {return "red"}
            else    { return "black" }
        ;})

        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })       
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.type); })      
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {      
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div.html(d.URL) 
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: There is a method called [padding](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#point_padding). Just do `var y = d3.scalePoint().range([height, 0]).padding(valueBetween0and1)`.

Comment: Work perfectly, thanks a lot!